# Docker image running failed locally but passed to github actions

Tags: node.js, docker

When I tried to build the docker image, it build passed but when I ran it locally, it failed but It passed when I ran it to github actions.

```
FROM node:18-buster
RUN addgroup teams
RUN adduser raj
RUN usermod -a -G teams raj
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod -R 777 /app
USER raj
COPY *package*json /app
RUN yarn install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn", "run", "test" ]
```

Comment: Which version of node are you running locally. I have seen problems like this when your system version is different from the version on docker. Also please write what tests are failing and with what error you get

Comment: How's it failing? What error do you see when you build locally? Also it would be better if you post your docker-build commands and your folder structure

Comment: @ManosKounelakis locally I have been using Nodejs `18.12.1` and as you see, I am using base image `node:18-buster`.

Comment: Ok. But please tell us more. What exactly is failing? What error messages do you get ? We don't have enough info to help you with the debugging process

Comment: @Fcmam5 About building the image, it passed but when I tried to run it, it failed locally but passed in github actions.

```
docker run node-app
yarn run v1.22.19
$ jest --coverage
PASS src/Strings/04/index.test.ts
PASS src/Strings/02/index.test.ts
PASS src/Strings/03/index.test.ts

        Failed to write coverage reports:
        ERROR: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/coverage/coverage-final.json'
        STACK: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/coverage/coverage-final.json'
```

Comment: @ManosKounelakis It says `permission denied`.

Comment: The permission denied occurred when I ran the test using `docker run` and when the test finished, it generated a report, so that is where I am getting permission denied, The reason is I am creating a new user and a group, I prefixed those step to the top to have access but don't know why the new user doesn't have the permission. I have tried to give access by running this command `RUN chmod -R 777 /app` but still the same result occurred. When I don't create the user, everything works perfectly. So I don't know how to give a new user permission to a directory in recursively.